# Google Maps API 3 - Click a poly line, return the clicked segment

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-polyline

I have a route made up of Lat and Longs.
I add these into an array and plot this "path" onto the map as a Polyline.

If the user clicks the route I need to know which part of the path (segment) he/she clicked on.

JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bazzlad/aVecC/2/

Code:

```
var map;
 $(document).ready(function () {
     initialize();
     addPolyline();
 });

 function initialize() {
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
     var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 4,
         center: myLatlng,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
         mapTypeControl: true,
         mapTypeControlOptions: {
             style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
         },
         panControl: true,
         panControlOptions: {
             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
         },
         zoomControl: true,
         zoomControlOptions: {
             style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
         },
         scaleControl: true,
         scaleControlOptions: {
             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
         },
         streetViewControl: true,
         streetViewControlOptions: {
             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
         }
     };

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

 }

 function addPolyline() {
     var routeArrLatLon = [];
     var routeArr = [
         [0, 0],
         [1, 0],
         [2, 1],
         [3, 0],
         [4, 2],
         [5, 0],
         [6, 3],
         [7, 0],
         [8, 4],
         [9, 0]
     ];

     $(routeArr).each(function (i) {
         routeArrLatLon.push(new google.maps.LatLng(routeArr[i][0], routeArr[i][1]));
     });




     var currentRoute = new google.maps.Polyline({
         path: routeArrLatLon,
         geodesic: true,
         strokeColor: '#FF0000',
         strokeOpacity: 1.0,
         strokeWeight: 5
     });


     currentRoute.setMap(map);


     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     currentRoute.getPath().forEach(function (e) { //can't do polyline.getPath()[i] because it's a MVCArray
         bounds.extend(e);
     });
     map.fitBounds(bounds);

     google.maps.event.addListener(currentRoute, 'click', function (event) {

         var myContent = '<div id="content">asdasd</div>';

         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
             content: myContent,
         });

         infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
         infowindow.open(map);

     });


 }
```

Comment: Referring to deleted comment about `PolyMouseEvent` edge, path and vertex: That works only if option `editable: true` is used. Otherwise you will have to calculate if point is on some of the lines.